# Use Gradle Witness plugin with java-library

Tags: java, maven, gradle

For a long time I was using Gradle with the `java` plugin, and Gradle Witness to verify Maven dependencies. e.g.:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'witness'

dependencies {
    compile "io.netty:netty-all:4.0.30.Final"
}

dependencyVerification {
    verify = [
        'io.netty:netty-all:1578cbb1354f02951c6ce5d374962e703afb882321164db9e3a2cfb141a1ebeb'
    ]
}
```

I would like to switch to the `java-library` plugin now, but it doesn't seem to be compatible with Witness. The build fails with the following error: `No dependency for integrity assertion found: io.netty:netty-all`

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'witness'

dependencies {
    implementation "io.netty:netty-all:4.0.30.Final"
}

dependencyVerification {
    verify = [
        'io.netty:netty-all:1578cbb1354f02951c6ce5d374962e703afb882321164db9e3a2cfb141a1ebeb'
    ]
}
```

The project I work on is security-sensitive and we need to be able to verify the dependencies' exact checksums (and not just the `PGP` signatures).

Is there any way to help `Witness` figure things out or a different plugin that has the same functionality? Unfortunately Witness [hasn't been updated since 2014](https://github.com/signalapp/gradle-witness) and seems to be unmaintained.

Comment: Seems that I'm not the only one missing the feature: https://github.com/akwizgran/gradle-witness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[checksum-dependency-plugin](https://github.com/vlsi/vlsi-release-plugins#checksum-dependency-plugin) should cover all the cases.

Sample integration: https://github.com/trezor/trezor-android/pull/53

Key features there:

1. The plugin itself does not try to play/resolve configurations. It should transparently support all tasks and other Gradle plugins.
2. Checksums for plugins (!) are verified as well. In other words, class files from bad jars never start to execute.
3. The plugin adds a task `allDependencies` which is basically a Gradle's default `dependencies` task that is added to all the projects.
4. The plugin generates `rootDir/build/checksum/checksum.xml` file (so you can review it). On top of that you could add `-PchecksumUpdate` to update checksums/PGP keys.
5. [PGP signatures verification](https://github.com/vlsi/vlsi-release-plugins/blob/d6353f3343d4f3eb202806cce8a09cddb6fc8560/checksum.xml#L35-L36)

Comment: Thank you! I opened a new issue on the RSK project to evaluate it: https://github.com/rsksmart/rskj/issues/947